# How to apply the backstrech plugin to a div, not body tag?

Tags: jquery, css

How can apply the [backstrech plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to a div, not the entire height of the body? I've searched to see if someone already did something like this but haven't found it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"><!-- div is 100% width - here is where I want to apply the backstrech --></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands you can't.

The backstretch plugin doesn't accept a selector.

You could take a fork of the project on github and add this support. I wouldn't think it'd be too hard.

**Update**

Looking at the source code there is one other way I can see to do this.

The plugin looks for an element with an ID of "backstretch" and specifying this as the Id of your div makes the plugin populate the div rather than the body.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AVHEE/)

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be in https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/blob/master/jquery.backstretch.js line 138 change `$("body").append($container);` to `$("#content").append($container);`

Please note I never used this plugin, it may not work or be easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use plugin for background image stretching. You can do it with CSS using CSS3 [background-size: cover property](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-cover.html) and for IE you can use [this solution](http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2011/01/ie-78-stretching-background-image-to.html)

[CSS3 background size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size)